# Matplotlib major and minor ticks not in sync

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code looks like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
hours = dates.HourLocator(interval = 2)
h_fmt = dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

ax.plot(times, y_values)

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
xmin_0 = math.ceil(xmin) # Rounding up to start of day
ax.set_xlim(xmin_0,)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=20))
```

The problem is that, as the picture shows, the major and minor x ticks don't seem to line up.

I've tried setting the x axis to start at 0, which it didn't do automatically, but to no avail.

'times' is an array of datetimes in the form: '2018-02-04 00:00:00'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interval` specifies the interval, but not the start point. One would hence rather specify the minutes to tick,

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(byminute=(0,20,40)))
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, no data needed :)